# iOS : Call a method just one time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Hi I was wondering how can I call a method just for one time in application life ... My application should download some files from server and I need do it just for one time; I mean  mean just one time per installation

here is my method

```
//Download some images from server and save it into directory 

- (void) downloadCovers {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    [self saveFile:@"mag1" ofType:@"png" fromURL:@"http://myweb.com/mag1.png" inDirectory:documentsDirectory];

}
```

and this method set images as UIButton BG :

```
  - (void)buttonsBGImage {

       UIImage * bgMag1 = [self loadImage:@"mag1" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];

        [mag1 setBackgroundImage:bgMag1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         NSLog(@"BG IS SET");

    }
```

Comment: You mean just one time _per installation_? Or per run of the app?

Comment: I'm confused by the question. If you want to call a method just once, then call it once! [self methodName];

Comment: `#ifndef something
//here's the code;
#endif`

Comment: just one time per installation...
@JackHumphries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a flag as a NSUserDefaults key and check for this NSUserDefault value in your downloadCovers method. If it is already set, do nothing, else download files and set the flag to true.

Like so:

```
-(void) downloadCovers {
BOOL downloaded = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"downloaded"];
if (!downloaded) {
     //download code here
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey: @"downloaded"];
    }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

why not just testing if the file is exist or not in local storage!

```
//Download some images from server and save it into directory 

- (void) downloadCovers {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathToImg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mag1.png",documentsDirectory];
    BOOL isExist = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:pathToImg];
    if (!isExist) {
        [self saveFile:@"mag1" ofType:@"png" fromURL:@"http://myweb.com/mag1.png" inDirectory:documentsDirectory];
    }

}
```

Comment: This.  You do not want to base this on a user default or other mechanism. If the file exists, use it.  If not, [re-]download.  Note that, at some point, it is almost guaranteed you'll want a "refresh" feature and keeping this dead simple will make that easier.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it for a method, but you can do it for a function using `pthread_once`:

```
static pthread_once_t once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
pthread_once(& once, SomeFunction);
```

or you can execute a block once using `dispatch_once` (the most natural choice for your current implementation).

In some cases (not this one), you may also prefer to do your work in `+initialize`.

**EDIT: Question was clarified**

Just check for the file's existence, or use a preference if you want this to persist across multiple launches.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)buttonsBGImage {

        if (!mag1.backgroundImage){
             UIImage * bgMag1 = [self loadImage:@"mag1" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];

               [mag1 setBackgroundImage:bgMag1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
               NSLog(@"BG IS SET");
        }

    }
```