# Method Called only After App Update

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Scenario , where i have to call a Method only once , whenever a User Will Update the Application or make a Fresh Install.
SO my Question is there is any particular Method to be called in App Delegate , After We update the Application , so if someone can tell me a another way to Achieve this , that would be really appreciated.

Comment: No its not just about one time , its about every time app version Update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would set a value in NSUserDefaults after you have called the function one time.  See the accepted answer here: [iOS : Call a method just one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968310/ios-call-a-method-just-one-time)

If you need to run after an update, you should include an always increasing number, or pull the build number, and check against the saved value.  This will allow you to know if the app has been updated.

Comment: Yes i am doing the Same , Saving Old Version number in NSUserDefaults and Check with the Current Version , if they are not Equal then Use the Method.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing following function which uniquely checks if user has rated the current version, [self nowRate] is the function, please change this to whatever action you want to perform uniquely per version

```
-(void)rateApp {
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSMutableDictionary*appRatedForVersion = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation].allKeys containsObject:@"AppRateDictionaryData"]){
    NSData *versionRateData = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppRateDictionaryData"];
    appRatedForVersion = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:versionRateData];
    if ([appRatedForVersion objectForKey:version] != nil) {
        NSNumber *isAppRatedForCurrentVersion = [appRatedForVersion objectForKey:version];
        BOOL hasBeenRated = [isAppRatedForCurrentVersion boolValue];
        if (hasBeenRated) {
            //Action already performed in this version do whatever you like
        } else {
            [self nowRate];
        }
    } else {
        [appRatedForVersion setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:version];
        NSData *versionRateData1 = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:appRatedForVersion];
        [defaults setObject:versionRateData1 forKey:@"AppRateDictionaryData"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        [self nowRate];
    }
} else {
    [appRatedForVersion setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:version];
    NSData *versionRateData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:appRatedForVersion];
    [defaults setObject:versionRateData forKey:@"AppRateDictionaryData"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [self nowRate];
}
```

}