# Run a quick set of procedures when a user updates an iOS app from the App Store

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, appdelegate

I have an application in the App Store. I'm making changes to a new version (1.2.0) and when the user updates the app in the App Store, I want the app to run a set of tutorials. Running the tutorials is not a problem; it's the question of is there a method in the AppDelegate or somewhere that only gets run the VERY first time the user runs the app after updating?

I've seen this SO question [iOS : Call a method just one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968310/ios-call-a-method-just-one-time) which points to the use of NSUserDefaults and that's great, but how would I deploy that for a specific version number and in my case?

Simply, I want to run some code that states "if user running < 1.2.0 and updates to 1.2.0, run this code, else, ignore". The same way when update an app, there's a few screens that displays only the very first time.

I'm sorry this is generic, but I'm not entirely sure where I would run this code. My storyboard has the initial root view controller set to the Tab Bar Controller. Could I set this in the first Table View that gets displayed when the user runs the app? If so, how would I go about doing something like that?

UPDATE: 
In my AppDelegate didFinishLaunching, I put the following code:

```
NSString* version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSLog(@"Version is %@", version); 

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:version forKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

In my Timeline Table View (the first view that gets called), in the viewDidLoad, I put:

```
self.appVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];


if ([self.appVersion isEqualToString:@"1.2.0"])
{
    if ([TutorialViewController hasSeenTutorial] == NO)
    {
        NSArray *tutorialImages = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        tutorialImages = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"TimelineTut.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tut 1.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tutty 2.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"newtut3.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"newnewtut4colors.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"newtut5.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"tut 6.png"]];
        TutorialViewController *tutorial = [[TutorialViewController alloc] initWithImages:tutorialImages];
        [self presentViewController:tutorial animated:YES completion:nil];
        [TutorialViewController setHasSeenTutorial:YES];

    }

}
```

But when I update from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0, it doesn't play the tutorial.

Any guidance would be really great with this.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need to save the version in user defaults, you can always get it from the bundle. Are you sure the version string is exactly 1.2.0? Does it work with an AdHoc install of your new app over an old app version?

Comment: And your "hasSeenTutorial" function probably sets a flag in the user defaults (which then are synchronised)? That should probably be not a boolean, but the version number, otherwise the next app update will see "hasSeenTutorial" = true ...

Comment: Thanks @TheEye - you were correct with that and the hasSeenTutorial boolean, I changed it to the version number and that did the trick. Now when I download the app from the app store and then update it using Xcode to 1.2.0, it plays the tutorial. Many thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the version number of an app with

```
NSString* version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

Save this in the user defaults, and when you update the app it can read the last installed version from the user defaults and react properly.

Comment: Thanks @TheEye - this is very helpful. Would I put this in the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as the most logical place to create this code, set it in NSUserDefaults and perform the check?

Comment: Either in your AppDelegate, or in the first view you show - depends on when you want to run the tutorials. You might want to show the first view in the background, and ask the user whether he wants to run the tutorials in a dialog on top of it, for example.

Comment: That's really helpful @TheEye and that works like a treat. The only thing that's happening now is that if I close off the app from the Multitasking and reopen it, it runs the "tutorial" again because it's reading from NSUserDefaults. So in my AppDelegate, I'm saving the version to NSUserDefaults as per your code above and in the first view I show (Timeline), I call NSUserDefaults for that key and if the version isEqualToString:@"1.2.0", it runs the tutorial.. I understand logically why the tutorial keeps getting called, but not sure how to only have it call the first time only?

Comment: Unless I set some sort of BOOL to say "hasSeenTutorial" and set that in my viewDidLoad for the Tutorial...

Comment: Sorry - I've just updated my question to include some code that I've put in. I set the BOOL and that works to not display the tutorial every time, however when I downloaded the app from the App Store (version 1.1.0) and then updated to 1.2.0 from my build in Xcode, it didn't display the tutorial when the app was run.. am I missing something? sorry for so many questions but I really thank you for your time with this.

Comment: You have to save the user defaults after setting them, otherwise they are not persisted over closing the app - [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Answer (score 1):

You could use the NSUserDefaults to check if the application has been run for the first time in this version then perform the tutorial code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @iamluke - I have updated my question but when updating the app, the tutorial ins't running - do you have any ideas to this? Thanks

Comment: Hi there forgive me for just pasting code but I'm about to go to bed! However something like this should work http://pastebin.com/wbpb8504

Comment: Many thanks for the code iamluke - that did work to some extent and I had to use a combination of your code and the selected answer. Many thanks for your work with this - I really appreciate it!